# wireless connection

Tags: wireless, networking

Since getting a Linksys E900 router Ubuntu 12.04 will not connect, same laptop (dual boot) Windows 7 does connect, same laptop, different house Ubuntu does connect. first router Linksys E900 firmware 10.0.03, second router Linksys E1500 firmware 10.0.0. Wireless card is a Broadcom and driver is installed. I'm thinking there is something in the firmware upgrade that needs to be addressed in the network manager's software. Both router's security is WPA2 Personal. Please help.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
wl                   2906597  0 
cfg80211              178877  1 wl
lib80211               14040  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I ran the commands and rebooted and still no connection, see terminal output below:

```
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe -r wl 
[sudo] password for dmcd: 
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  bcmwl-kernel-source* 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
After this operation, 3,656 kB disk space will be freed. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y 
(Reading database ... 170284 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing bcmwl-kernel-source ... 
Removing all DKMS Modules 
Done. 
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) 
Purging configuration files for bcmwl-kernel-source ... 
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) 
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ... 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic 
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe brcsmac 
FATAL: Module brcsmac not found. 
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$
```

---

#### EDIT

now I have a false connect, see terminal output below:

`nm-tool` output:

```
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [McCisco] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:26:82:99:44:D3

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Thomson5A1815:   Infra, 00:24:17:BC:E5:77, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 75 WPA
    McKay:           Infra, 00:18:F8:3E:D5:B6, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 45 WPA
    OWNER-PC_Network:Infra, 90:F6:52:C3:11:56, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    BELL586:         Infra, 2C:E4:12:90:59:79, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    belkinSP:        Infra, 00:17:3F:5A:5E:16, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA
    Bogdan:          Infra, 50:3D:E5:30:A5:50, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA2
    galacticempire:  Infra, 28:CF:DA:B7:6E:4F, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    kalana:          Infra, 00:40:F4:E3:D3:12, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WEP
    cancun1:         Infra, 00:26:5A:C8:E9:7D, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WEP
    BELL768:         Infra, 00:26:50:9E:03:91, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WEP
    *McCisco:        Infra, C8:D7:19:CF:3F:7A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 58 WPA2
    Leano Wireless:  Infra, 34:EF:44:97:CB:C1, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA
    NETGEAR-3G:      Infra, C4:3D:C7:6A:FA:3C, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA2
    BELL513:         Infra, 3C:EA:4F:BC:AB:31, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WEP

  IPv6 Settings:
    Address:         fd11:cc97:526d:0:71e5:7a5d:3419:d561
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fd11:cc97:526d:0:226:82ff:fe99:44d3
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fe80::226:82ff:fe99:44d3
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::



- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        C8:0A:A9:C8:17:65

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

`route -n` output:

```
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Here are outputs from the nm-tool command while trying to connect and after failed connect:

```
dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connecting

- Device: wlan0  [McCisco] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             connecting (getting IP configuration)
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:26:82:99:44:D3

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Thomson5A1815:   Infra, 00:24:17:BC:E5:77, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    McKay:           Infra, 00:18:F8:3E:D5:B6, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA
    OWNER-PC_Network:Infra, 90:F6:52:C3:11:56, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    belkinSP:        Infra, 00:17:3F:5A:5E:16, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA
    BELL586:         Infra, 2C:E4:12:90:59:79, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA WPA2
    galacticempire:  Infra, 28:CF:DA:B7:6E:4F, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    kalana:          Infra, 00:40:F4:E3:D3:12, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WEP
    cancun1:         Infra, 00:26:5A:C8:E9:7D, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WEP
    BELL768:         Infra, 00:26:50:9E:03:91, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WEP
    NETGEAR-3G:      Infra, C4:3D:C7:6A:FA:3C, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
    McCisco:         Infra, C8:D7:19:CF:3F:7A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA2


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        C8:0A:A9:C8:17:65

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


dmcd@dmcd-Presario-CQ62-Notebook-PC:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmsmac
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:26:82:99:44:D3

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Thomson5A1815:   Infra, 00:24:17:BC:E5:77, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA
    McKay:           Infra, 00:18:F8:3E:D5:B6, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA
    OWNER-PC_Network:Infra, 90:F6:52:C3:11:56, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    belkinSP:        Infra, 00:17:3F:5A:5E:16, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA
    BELL586:         Infra, 2C:E4:12:90:59:79, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA WPA2
    galacticempire:  Infra, 28:CF:DA:B7:6E:4F, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA2
    kalana:          Infra, 00:40:F4:E3:D3:12, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WEP
    cancun1:         Infra, 00:26:5A:C8:E9:7D, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WEP
    BELL768:         Infra, 00:26:50:9E:03:91, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WEP
    NETGEAR-3G:      Infra, C4:3D:C7:6A:FA:3C, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
    McCisco:         Infra, C8:D7:19:CF:3F:7A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA2


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        C8:0A:A9:C8:17:65

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add some additional details: lspci -nn | grep 0280; lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43 -e brcmsmac; iwconfig

Comment: Please edit your question to conform to some kind of grammar. I wasn’t able to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the driver *wl* is incorrect for your device 14e4:4727. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

You wireless should be working now; however, it might take a reboot.

Comment: It is not brcsmac; it is brcmsmac.

Comment: Right you are, I noticed my mistake right after editing, and ran the proper command. I got a false connection, looked good on the screen but wouldn't open a browser.

Comment: I took the laptop out to the local coffee shop and connected to their free wifi right away, I still think there is something new in Cisco's 10.0.03 firmware.

Comment: When you have a "false connection," please run and post: nm-tool and also route -n. Do you have any DNS nameservers set up in your router as I do? Please see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/router_DNS.png

Comment: after initial false connect I reinstalled broadcom driver. I ran the three commands again, and no connection of any kind today.

Comment: DNS values are all zeros

Comment: false connect occurs after removing ethernet cable.

Comment: @user137024 you just attempted to edit chili's answer to include your `nm-tool` and `route -n` output. You should edit your own question, not the answer. I have went ahead and edited your question to include the output on your behalf, but just remember that you need to edit your question =).

Comment: You reinstalled the proprietary Broadcom driver that is wrong for your device? Why?? You are not getting an IPv4 address nor DNS nameservers from the router. I agree that it is probably a misconfiguration issue in the router and therefor beyond the scope of askubuntu.

Comment: above edit has broadcom purged again

Comment: android tablet, android phone, and windows 7 all connect wirelessly to router as configured

Comment: this laptop with previously installed broadcom driver connected to my son's cisco router

Comment: thanks Alaa, please forgive my post/edit etiquette ignorance.

Comment: I don't know how, but I'm connected now. got an update on openSUSE and it connected and now Ubuntu. Go figure!

Comment: Glad it's working by whatever means.